# curl　を使ってパソコン内のファイルを指定したい

Tags: curl

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg" -F "threshold=0.6" -F "owners=me" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2018-03-19"
```

上記が提供されているサンプルコードです。
その中の　"images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg"　を自分のパソコン内に保存している画像ファイルにしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「curlの実行する環境」と「自分のパソコン」は同じですか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。頂いた回答の内容が完全には理解できず大変申し訳ないのですが、現状、自分のマックに入っているターミナルでコードを入力しています。画像はWatsonにアップロードすることになっているはずです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サンプルコードのオプション `-F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg"` は、ファイル fruitbowl.jpg に images_file という名前を付けて POST メソッドでアップロードするものです。
（`-F, --form <name=content>`）

fruitbowl.jpg の代わりに foo.png をアップロードしたいのであれば `-F "images_file=@foo.png"` とすれば良いです。
ただし `foo.png` はシェルのカレントディレクトリの `foo.png` であることに注意してください。
もし /Users/xxx/Pictures/foo.png をこのアップロードしたいのであれば、次のようにする必要があります。

```
cd ~/Pictures
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@foo.png" # ... 後略
```

あるいは絶対パスでファイルを指定することも可能です。この場合はディレクトリを移動する必要はありません。

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@/Users/xxx/Pictures/foo.png" # ... 後略
```

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。curl -X POST -F "images_file=@Users/daitoryo/Downloads/download.jpg“ # -F "classifier_ids=food" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2018-03-19"

上記の通り入力しましたが、下記の通りうまくいきませんでした。
何が原因なのでしょうか。。。XD

[1] 13537
Daitoryo-MacBook-Air:~ daitoryo$ curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Comment: jpgのあとのダブルクオートが不正です。その直後のシャープは消してください。アットマークとUsersの間にスラッシュが必要です。api-keyはなにか実際の値をいれる必要があります。